# Each page of simple page application as a separate app

Tags: elm

Currently, I have no way to structure my pages as separate apps. The way I am currently thinking is as follows:

- The `App` / `Main` file is the bootstrapper which provides the routing.
- The blog is a seperate app with its own update, models and REST calls.
- When switching to another route (e.g. photo albums), it will start up another Elm app with its own update, modes, et cetera.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here (is this all front-end routing you mean?). Anyways: sure you can have 3 different completely independent elm apps, each with their own url, their own index.html, and their own main.elm, own model, update and REST. Then your user can navigate from one app to another simply by rendering a link with the (external) url for the other page. Is that what you are looking for? Or do all 3 apps have to run and display stuff at the same time?

Comment: @wintvelt you're on the right track. I want to achieve a separation between *all* pages. Just because a blog doesn't need to be interlaced with a photo album. Is there any literature on how you can achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are different ways to achieve this:

**1. One Elm app, with each page as a separate component**

In that case, you create one "root" elm module, which imports your photo Model, Msg, init, update, view.
And same for your blog.

Then you have 1 elm app. This is the approach I would take: 
Allows you to manage global front-end state, like user-info in one place and across photo and blog.

Your main elm file would then look something like this:

```
import PhotoPage
import BlogPage

type alias Model =
  { photo : PhotoPage.Model
  , blog : BlogPage.Model
  , currentPage : Page
  }

type Page = Home | Blog | Photo

init = 
  { photo = PhotoPage.init
  , blog = BlogPage.init
  , currentPage = Home
  }

type Msg =
  GoHome
  | PhotoMsg PhotoPage.Msg
  | BlogMsg BlogPage.Msg

update msg model =
  case msg of
    PhotoMsg photoMsg ->
      let
        (newPhoto, photoCmd) = PhotoPage.update photoMsg model.photo
      in
        { model | photo = newPhoto }
        ! [ Cmd.map PhotoMsg photoCmd ]
```

**2. Completely separate elm apps**

Build 3 completely independent apps/ websites, each with own index.html, and own elm app.

And you use default browser navigation to navigate between your different Elm apps.

This could work if you have some way to manage global state at server/ session level.

Your view function in your home.elm file could then look something like this:

```
view model =
  div []
   [ h1 [] [ text "I am the homepage"]
   , a [ href "/photo" ] [ text "go to photo page" ]
   ]
```

Comment: I was already really close myself, but since I am using Hop, I had an abstraction. Due to being somewhat unfamiliar with the syntax, I didn't see what my mistake was. But this answer was really helpful. For future readers: for more literature, you can read good documentation here: https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/02-elm-arch/06-composing.html

Comment: It would be good to point out that using "components" for everything is being discouraged in Elm. Separate pages (as in your question) are exception rather than the rule. A good description of how to scale Elm can be found [in the official guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/). Another good source is [this blog post on building a SPA in Elm](http://7sharpnine.com/2016/10/03/building-an-spa-with-elm/) or [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/knewter/time-tracker)